# Invariant subspaces of $\begin{pmatrix}1 & 1\\ -1 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$

Tags: linear-algebra

> How many invariant subspaces $$\begin{pmatrix}1 & 1\\
>  -1 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$$ has?

There are at least 2 invariant subspaces: $\mathbb{R}^2$ and $\{0\}$.

The matrix of the operator is non-singular, hence, its image coincides with $\mathbb{R}^2$ and the kernel with $\{0\}$. So, we have still only 2 subspaces.

How do I prove that there are no more?

Comment: Let $V$ be an invariant subspace with dimension $1$. One has $V=\{\lambda v\colon \lambda \in \mathbb R\}$, for some non-null $v$, with $v=\begin{bmatrix}v_1\\ v_2 \end{bmatrix}$ for some real numbers $v_1, v_2$. Now compare the image of $v$ with the elements of $V$ and see if you can have subspaces with dimension $1$.

Comment: So, I solved system $\begin{cases}
v_1+v_2=\lambda v_1\\
-v_1+v_2=\lambda v_2
\end{cases}$ and got $\lambda = 0$. Hence, there are only 2 subspaces. Right?

Comment: I just realize that, basically, I was searching for eigenspace, right? Does that mean that a map have invariant subspaces only among trivial ones, kernel/image & eigenspaces?

Comment: Right. No, it works out that way in this case because the dimension of the larger vector space is $2$, this is crucial for the argument.

Comment: Thank you for hint and explanation very much.

Comment: Well, if we call the matrix $A$ and if $V$ (from Git Gud's comment) is invariant under $A,$ then in particular $Av=\lambda v$ for some real $\lambda,$ so $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $A$. But what *are* the eigenvalues of $A$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your matrix does not have eigenvalues over the field $\mathbb{R}$, the only invariant subspaces would be the trivial ones you listed. Over $\mathbb{C}$ it is diagonalizable and so there are two additional invariant subspaces, namely the spaces spanned by the vectors $(i,1)$ and $(-i,1)$ respectively.

Answer (score 1):

the matrix $$\pmatrix{1&1\\-1&1} = \sqrt 2\pmatrix{\cos (-\pi/4) & -\sin (-\pi/4)\\\sin (-\pi/4)&\cos (-\pi/4)}$$ represents a rotation by $-\pi/4$(quarter revolution clockwise) followed by magnification by a factor of $\sqrt 2.$  that means this transformation cannot have a one dimensional real invariant space.